# During startup - Warning message: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found in windows Rstudio eventhough stats package works in R

Tags: r

I have tried multiple reinstallation of R and Rstudios but following problem is presistent. Any help with this will be highly appreciated.
R version is 4.2.2
and Rstudio is 2022.12.0.-353

```
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The network path was not found.
[Workspace loaded from ~/.RData]

Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

There should not be this error, I was following the tutorial exactly.

Comment: First thing to do is delete the hidden .Rdata file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the package window and see if the `stats` is checked or not. If it's not checked, check it and install/or update it using the GUI. This worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Adding R to the PATH solved it. Here is how to do it: https://softwaresaved.github.io/distance-consultancy/develop/SetUpDevelopmentR.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34652134)

Answer (score 0):

Adding R directories to $PATH variable didn't work out for me. First off, I deleted everything related to R ([link](https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-uninstall-r-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu/)) + hidden .R files. Next I also got rid of folders below:

```
/opt/R/R.X.X
/opt/../OpenBLAS/
```

Additionally, I removed *libblas.so.3* file (Not sure it is necessary). Then I reinstalled it (different versions of it exist, [link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libblas.so.3)):

```
sudo apt install -y libopenblas0-serial
```

After that everything is running smoothly