# Rstudio won't load packages but base R will

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

About a month ago, I updated R and Rstudio and downloaded Rtools. I had trouble getting rstan to run, and somehow messed up Rstudio so it can't find libraries. When I open Rstudio, I get the error:

```
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I can install packages, but never load them. An example when trying to load ggplot2:

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything. Changed the path. And even had IT rebuild my profile. But for whatever reason, I cannot load any packages in Rstudio. Base R works, but Rstudio will not.

Has anyone encountered something similar? Please help!

Comment: Perhaps related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956163/during-startup-warning-message-package-stats-in-optionsdefaultpackages ?

Comment: For anyone who may stumble upon this in the future, the solution was simple in the end -- which we figured out after a profile rebuild, hours of IT support, and a loaner laptop. I had unintentionally edited the .Renviron path [and startup files are important](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-access-index-for-repository-warning-in-install-packages/111314/8). Used version history to figure out the original path and _voila_. Fixed. 

I hope this helps someone else.